# Como hacer focus a una ventana de windows forms luego de elegirla con ALT+TAB?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de windows forms y tengo el siguiente problema:

> Yo puedo salir de la ventana con la tecla escape(esta manejado el evento de key down).
>
> El problema es que cuando estoy en la aplicacion y aperti alt+tab para ir a otra aplicación que tenga abierta y luego vuelvo a mi app, no me funciona ninguna tecla(tengo que hacer click dentro del formulario para que funcione).

¿Qué evento tengo que usar para darme cuenta que abrieron la app nuevamente con alt+tab?

Answer (score 0):

Depende como tengas hecha tu aplicación. En tu caso usas MDI, FormTabbed o que estilo?.

También puedes verificar como estas manejando el evento key down que no sea quien te este creando problemas ya que al seleccionar una aplicación esta debe mostrarse sin mayores inconvenientes.

Saludos